# In OpenMp using more threads slows down my programme. Serial is faster than

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, openmp

My OpenMP programme becomes slower the more threads I use. I tried arraypadding (read about false sharing) as a solution which didnt help. Do you know solutions?

StringLength is the length of String1 and String2. For a string of length ~60k it takes about 20 sec with one thread and 50 sec with 16 threads.

The whole programme has another loop similar to this one. So 2 loops in total thats it. It is run on a cluster with 2 Intel Xeon octa-core. It is run with g++ and -O2.

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(p3, p1,p2, string1,string2, maxLen) num_threads(16)  default(none) 
    {
    for (int i = 3; i <= StringLength+ 1; i++) {
        #pragma omp for schedule(static, 5000) 
        for (int j = 1; j < i - 1; j++) {
            p3[j] = min({ p2[j - 1] + 1, p2[j] + 1, p1[j - 1] + (string1[j] == string2[i - j]) });
        }
        #pragma omp single
        {
            p3[i - 1] = i - 1;
            p3[0] = i - 1;
            swap(p1,p2);
            swap(p2,p3);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"programme becomes slower"* - what does it mean *slower*? How long does it take?

Comment: Can you `-O3` which is "actually optimized" as opposed to "sort of kind of maybe optimized a bit" with `-O2`?

Comment: The number of threads should be proportional to the number of cores. For 2 cores, 16 threads is burying the CPUs in tasks. Performance will drop off sharply as the number of threads exceeds the number of available cores.

Comment: When you say "cluster" you're confusing the issue here. Is this one machine, or a group of machines?

Comment: For what it's worth, if this is just simple math, this is what a GPU kernel function excels at. I'd also look for a better algorithm. What does this even do?

Comment: Just tried -O3. It is actually slower :). 57 seconds 1 thread. 102 seconds 16 threads.

Comment: Are you running this on one machine, or trying to spread this out over multiple machines?

Comment: If this is a bioinformatics problem there's probably a much better algorithm.

Comment: Documentation says one node can support 32 threads. So that is the maximum that I want to use.

Comment: There are probably other ways. But I thought my innocent looking for loops can be sped up :)

Comment: @HansPeter31 if you try with #pragma omp for schedule(static, 1) did it improve anything?

Comment: Maybe my problem has to do with autovectorization of the compiler?

PS: I just updated the code. I forgot to include the pragma omp single around the copy instructions.

Comment: @HansPeter31 What is the execution time for 2 4 8  threads?. What is the size of those strings?

Comment: @dreamcrash for schedule(static,1) 1 thread ~20 sec. 16 threads take between 80 sec and 10 min. For some reason there is some big variance here.
String length is ~60 - 65 k

Comment: What is the execution time for 2 4 8 threads?

Comment: schedule(static, 1): 2 threads 22 sec. 4 threads 34sec. 8 threads 49 sec.

Comment: So it does not scale it all!!!. Just for to check some remove the #pragma omp single and the code there

Comment: 1 thread 23 sec 16 threads 32 sec. So the loop doesnt scale as well. But why ?

Comment: You are missing the point first you need to test with 2 threads before going to 16, you much with 2 threads?

Comment: 1 thread 23. 2 threads 18.sec. without the single part. I get what you want now. It really cant handle too many threads.

Comment: t(1 thread) = t(2 threads) = 23 seconds. 

I think I will try to work on my algorithm to make this faster. Thanks a lot guys for the input!

Comment: @HansPeter31 Can you please edit your question with the copy method so that I can have a lot at that part?

Comment: I think the main problem is that you are doing only very few computations while accessing lots of different memory locations. Therefore you are memory bandwidth bound and not compute-bound. While this might not be avoidable, you could for example try to avoid the copies by swapping around some pointers. Are ```p1```, ```p2``` and ```p3``` C++ strings or raw ```char``` pointers?

Comment: In either case, you should be ables to use ```std::swap``` to exchange the (underlying) raw pointers. Think about it like renaming in every iteration of the ```i```-loop which memory location is labeled ```p1```, ```p2``` or ```p3```. With the copy operations being gone, the ```j```-loop might actually be the most expensive thing and you can try to optimize there. PS.: the ```int i, j;``` in the beginning does nothing, as the variable declarations in the loop declarations are shadowing them. Just get rid of that first line.

Comment: And like in @dreamcrash's answer, put the modifications of ```p3``` inside the single region. With all threads writing the same to that location, the data-race might not generate the wrong result, but it still makes no sense to do it more than once.

Comment: @Paul I would like too see the copy method to see if something can be done about it

Comment: I would guess, that it is ```std::copy```. But why copy, if you can also just "rename the arrays"?

Comment: yep that is actually a good point

Comment: swap makes it indeed faster. I use -O3. 1 thread 16 sec 2 threads 19 sec. 
p1 p2 p3 are int arrays. My goal is now to make some improvements on the paralellization of the loop

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to write the code in one for-loop. And also I did not use dynamic memory anymore.